# Oracle chr() diferent returns from SQL engine versus PL/SQL engine, why?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, chr

Same function, same argument, different outputs:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    n number := 122.5;
    c_plsql varchar2(1);
    c_sql   varchar2(1);
begin
    c_plsql := chr(n);
    select chr(n) into c_sql from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(c_plsql || ' ' || c_sql);
end;
/

{ z
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: Not in 21c, got z twice.
Post v$version and NLS settings.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE ENGLISH
NLS_TERRITORY AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS .,
NLS_CALENDAR GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_SORT BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS.FF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, chr() appears to be performing an implicit conversion to `binary_float` (IEEE 754 floating-point representation) as the datatype, as opposed to `number` (ANSI SQL NUMERIC). This results in different rounding results. I cannot duplicate your results on 19c unless I force the datatype, in which case I get the same results you do:

```
set serveroutput on; 
declare
    n1 number := 122.5;
    n2 double precision(10) := 122.5;
    n3 float := 122.5;
    n4 binary_double := 122.5;
    n5 binary_float := 122.5;
    
    c_plsql varchar2(1);
    c_sql   varchar2(1); begin
    c_plsql := chr(n1);
    select chr(n1) into c_sql from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('number: ' || c_plsql || ' ' || c_sql);

    c_plsql := chr(n2);
    select chr(n2) into c_sql from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('double: ' || c_plsql || ' ' || c_sql);

    c_plsql := chr(n3);
    select chr(n3) into c_sql from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('float : ' || c_plsql || ' ' || c_sql);

    c_plsql := chr(n4);
    select chr(n4) into c_sql from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('bindbl: ' || c_plsql || ' ' || c_sql);

    c_plsql := chr(n5);
    select chr(n5) into c_sql from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line('binflt: ' || c_plsql || ' ' || c_sql); end; 
/
```

with output:

```
number: z z
double: z z
float : z z
bindbl: { z
binflt: { z

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

When using binary_double or binary_float, the chr() function implicitly rounds the value of `n` up in PL/SQL. In all cases of SQL, or when using `number` in PL/SQL, chr() truncates the decimal portion of the number, effectively rounding down.